# Basic authentication - reskit -iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I want to use the restKit api
I need get info (json) from my web services from iOS. My web service has the basic authentication

[image]

I tried login with the following code:

```
RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://mysite.com"]; 
RKClient *client= [RKClient sharedClient]; 
    client.username = @"user"; 
    client.password = @"passw"; 
    client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;

RKRequest * therequest = [client requestWithResourcePath:@"/authentication"]; 
    [therequest setMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];                                       
    [therequest setDelegate:self];                               
    [therequest send];
```

But I cannot get it.

Please... can you give me an example for the basic authentication on restKit.

Best Regards!

Comment: Remove the `therequest.additionalHTTPHeaders` line, it should work fine.

Comment: Yes, I removed the line... But how can I know if the authentication works fine?   When the login is successfully return un Key for the request... how can I get this Key...   I am newest in iOS :(

Comment: Just look at the delegate methods: http://restkit.org/api/master/Protocols/RKRequestDelegate.html

Comment: Thanks!! It help me a lot ^_^  Just I get the following message 

Encountered unexpected response with status code: 200 (MIME Type: text/plain -> URL: http://api.mysite.com/authentication -- http://api.mysite.com -- http://api.mysite.com)

How can I get the KEY from my api site?  thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the following code:

```
 RKURL *baseURL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURLString:@"http://api.mysite.com"];
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    objectManager.client.baseURL = baseURL;    
    objectManager.client.username = @"user";
    objectManager.client.password = @"passw";

    objectManager.serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeXML;


    RKURL *URL = [RKURL URLWithBaseURL:[objectManager baseURL] resourcePath:@"/authentication"];

    NSLog(@"URL: %@", [URL absoluteString]);
    NSLog(@"resourcePath: %@", [URL resourcePath]);
    NSLog(@"query: %@", [URL query]);

    [objectManager loadObjectsAtResourcePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@", [URL resourcePath], [URL query]] delegate:self];
```

I wait that asnwer will help somebody

Comment: And I get the token from my site with:

    NSLog(@"HTTP bodyAsString:  %@", [response bodyAsString]);

Answer (score 0):

First thatnks for your correct answer,
could you please show us the web service how is look like.
coz i do my own but does not really work with ur code
this is my web service

```
$UserName = $_GET['u'];
    $Password = $_GET['p'];

    include("Ldap.php");

    $ldap = new Ldap();

    if($ldap->authenticate($UserName, $Password))
 {
        $json = array('status'=>'OK');
    }
    else
    {
        $json = array('status'=>'ERROR');
    }
```